# Use activity reference in a Service

Tags: android, android-activity, service, broadcastreceiver

I created an application that has got only a `Service`, launched by a `BroadcastReceiver`.

Now I have to implement a third-part library and to instantiate an object of that lib, i need to pass to the method an activity parameter.

That application doesn't have activity, is there a way to use an activity reference in the `Service` without launch it?

**WORKAROUND**

I'm using a workaround now: when receiver is called, it launches an activity that instantiates one object, then the activity launches the service killing itself.

Comment: Could you explain, why you need reference to Activity? Maybe there is another way?

Comment: "I created an application that has got only a Service, launched by a BroadcastReceiver" -- unless this is a plugin for some other app, or is going to be pre-installed on a device or ROM, it would seem like this app will never run on Android 3.1+. "is there a way to use an activity reference in the Service without launch it?" -- not really. Talk to the developers of this library and ask them.

Comment: Sounds like you need Activity just for the Context? Maybe Application context might be enough. If so, you could retrieve it using Application class.